# FORBIDDEN -- config update for existing channel did not pass initial checks: implicit policy evaluation failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, raft, hyperledger-fabric-orderer, hyperledger-fabric-peer

I'm trying to create an application channel for a hyperledger fabric network which consists of:

- certificate authority for all participants
- TLS certificate authority for ordering nodes and peers
- one ordering node
- one peer node

Below is my configtx.yaml:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: path/to/orderers/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies: &SampleOrgPolicies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

        OrdererEndpoints:
            - "localhost:7050"

        #  Anchor node (Anchor Peer)： Each organization can specify Anchor Peer, Nodes of other organizations can Gossip Message sent to this Anchor Peer On , , in turn, Anchor Peer Will get the whole network information , Block broadcast to the organization ;
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: localhost
              Port: 7051

    - &Org1

        Name: Org1MSP

        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: path/to/peer1/msp

        Policies: &Org1Policies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"

    - &Org2

        Name: Org2MSP

        ID: Org2MSP

        MSPDir: path/to/peer2/msp

        Policies: &Org2Policies
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
            Endorsment:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

        # AnchorPeers:
        #     - Host: localhost
        #       Port: 7051

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V2_0 capability ensures that orderers and peers behave according
        # to v2.0 channel capabilities. Orderers and peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V2_0 orderer capability ensures that orderers behave according
        # to v2.0 orderer capabilities. Orderers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 orderer capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V2_0 application capability ensures that peers behave according
        # to v2.0 application capabilities. Peers from
        # prior releases would behave in an incompatible way, and are therefore
        # not able to participate in channels at v2.0 application capability.
        # Prior to enabling V2.0 application capabilities, ensure that all
        # peers on channel are at v2.0.0 or later.
        V2_0: true

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies: &ApplicationPolicies
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    OrdererType: etcdraft
    # Addresses used to be the list of orderer addresses that clients and peers
    # could connect to.  However, this does not allow clients to associate orderer
    # addresses and orderer organizations which can be useful for things such
    # as TLS validation.  The preferred way to specify orderer addresses is now
    # to include the OrdererEndpoints item in your org definition
    Addresses:
        - localhost:7050

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: raft0
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: path/to/signcerts/raft0-tls-cert.pem
          ServerTLSCert: path/to/signcerts/raft0-tls-cert.pem
       

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies: &OrdererPolicies
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Capabilities:
          <<: *OrdererCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:
    TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

First, I create a genesis block with the following command:

```
./bin/configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis -configPath ./testConfigs -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis_block.pb -channelID mychannel
```

Next, I create a transaction to create an application channel:

```
./bin/osnadmin channel join --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --config-block ./channel-artifacts/genesis_block.pb -o localhost:7050 --ca-file "$ORDERER_CA" --client-cert "$ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT" --client-key "$ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY"
```

Every time I create an app channel, I get the following error:

```
Error: Post "https://localhost:7050/participation/v1/channels": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x00\x00\x06\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00@\x00"
```

Please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Why is there no anchor peer entry for Org1 in the YAML file? Try adding it to see what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

The symptom for my problem was the same:

```
"Error: Post "https://localhost:7050/participation/v1/channels": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x00\x00\x06\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00@\x00"
```

What I did wrong was to connect to the Orderer on its general listen address and missed to configure the Admin.* settings as described [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_channel/create_channel_participation.html#configure-the-orderer-yaml-file-for-each-orderer).

Once I connected to the Admin Listenaddress the osnadmin command worked correctly. The general port serves GRPC while the Admin one uses http(s). I think this explains the malformed error.